# Arithmetic Sequence problem - Word Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the smallest positive integer $a$ such that the number $2014$ is a term of the following arithmetic sequence $a, a+7, a+14, a+21$?

I have tried the use of $T_n = a + (n-1)d$ where it is clear $d=7$ and so a multiple of $7$ appears a reasonable assumption. However, it is the smallest starting integer value to be computed for which it is unclear what the best strategy is.

Comment: Which is the smallest positive integer $a$ such that $2014-a$ is a multiple of 7?

Comment: I have tried the use of Tn = a + (n-1)d where it is clear d=7 and so a multiple of 7 appears a reasonable assumption however it is the smallest starting integer value to be computed for which it is unclear what the best strategy is ?

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, 
$$2014=a+(n-1)7,\qquad\qquad (1)$$
and the problem is equivalent to finding the smallest positive integer for which (1) holds.

But $$2014=(288\times7)-2=(287\times7)+5=(286\times7)+12=\dots$$

Thus, $~~~a=5$.

Comment: Kind regards for all the assistance - made some progress independently while thinking around the multiples of 7 as the d variable, Ed